# change my code from multiprocessing to normal

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

in the following code i want to change the code from Multiprocessing to normal process.
this code wont work on windows machine for some reason also it will be better if there is not multiprocessing, any advice and help will be appreciated. thank you

```
 def fitness(self, generation):


        def determine_fitness(subgeneration,output,pos):

            fitness_array = np.zeros(np.shape(subgeneration)[0])

            for i in range(np.shape(subgeneration)[0]):

                individual = subgeneration[i,:]

                #Subset the columns based on this individual
                X_individual = self.dataset[[self.dataset.columns[j] for j in range(len(individual)) if individual[j] == 1]]

                #Split into train-test datasets
                X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_individual,self.response,test_size=self.test_size)

                #Fit the classifier
                self.algorithm.fit(X_train,y_train)

                #Report fitness score (score in the testing dataset)
                fitness = self.algorithm.score(X_test,y_test)

                #append to fitness array
                fitness_array[i] = fitness

            output.put((pos,fitness_array))


        process_output = mp.Queue()
        subarrays = np.array_split(generation,self.nprocs)
        processes = [mp.Process(target=determine_fitness,args=(subarrays[i],process_output,i)) for i in range(self.nprocs)]

        for p in processes:
            p.start()

        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        results = [process_output.get() for p in processes]
        results.sort()
        rlist = []
        for element in results:
            r = element[1]
            for j in range(len(r)):
                rlist.append(r[j])
        rlist = np.array(rlist)

        return rlist
```

Comment: If you managed to write multiprocessing code, how come you can't manage the simpler version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code just splits input generation object into several subgenerations and processes them simultaneously using multiprocessing. I've just removed that splitting and got the following code:

```
def fitness(self, generation):
    fitness_array = np.zeros(np.shape(generation)[0])

    for i in range(np.shape(generation)[0]):

        individual = generation[i,:]

        #Subset the columns based on this individual
        X_individual = self.dataset[[self.dataset.columns[j] for j in range(len(individual)) if individual[j] == 1]]

        #Split into train-test datasets
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_individual,self.response,test_size=self.test_size)

        #Fit the classifier
        self.algorithm.fit(X_train,y_train)

        #Report fitness score (score in the testing dataset)
        fitness = self.algorithm.score(X_test,y_test)

        #append to fitness array
        fitness_array[i] = fitness

    return fitness_array
```

Hope this works for you.